# In pairs loop messed up

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

A normal working code but it *doesn't work as i expected*, seriously but wth Lua

```
local Exceptions = {1,2,3,5,7}
local mt = {__mod = function(v1, v2)
  for i, v in pairs (v1) do 
    if v2 == v then 
      return true
    else
      return false 
    end 
  end 
end }
setmetatable(Exceptions, mt)
print(Exceptions % 2)
```

v2 == v ( inside Exceptions has 2 so it should return true, but hell no, it returned false. This is annoying)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You break out of the pairs() loop when you return the result of `v2 == v` comparison.
The value of 2 is never reached, you exit the `__mod` function prematurely, reporting the result of comparing 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

In your first loop run `v2` is `2` and `v` is `1`. As `2 ~= 1` you return false and that's it. No more iteration. Move `return false` after the loop.

```
local Exceptions = {1,2,3,5,7}
local mt = {__mod = function(v1, v2)
  for i, v in pairs (v1) do 
    if v2 == v then 
      return true
    end 
  end
  return false  
end }
setmetatable(Exceptions, mt)
print(Exceptions % 2)
```

Instead of

```
if v2 == v then 
  return true
else
  return false 
end
```

you could have simply written

```
return v2 == v
```

I personally would discourage altering the modulus operator for other things than calculating the modulus. I would have expected an element-wise modulus calcuation without seeing the implementation or any comment. Why not simply write a function `isInTable(someTable, someNumber)` that does the same? Same result, no confusion.

Comment: I was messing around with metatables and metamethods, then encounter this error. Thanks for answering me

Comment: Well, ```return v2 == v```    won't work and it will return false instead of true

Comment: @BlaztOne I don't get your point. I just told you that you can reduce YOUR code by 4 lines. as your code returns false for `2 == 1` my shorter version of it of course also returns false. the solution to your problem is written in the section above. `return v2 == v` was not intended to solve your problem. it cannot do that within the loop as it would also prematurely end it. it was just some additional advice